# How to make <form:input/> field readonly

Tags: html, readonly-attribute

readonly attribute is working on  field. But, it doesn't make form:input/ field readonly. I want it to work it on form:input/ field. can anyone help me regarding this?

Comment: share your code here.Your question is not clear

Comment: my input filed is like this <form:input type="text" class="form-control"
       path="bprMobile" maxlength="10"  readonly="true"/>if   I given readonly attribute it doesn't work. It works only when I given readonly="true". Thank You for responding.

Answer (score 3):

```html
<form>
  readonly
  <input value="foo" readonly /> read and write:
  <input value="bar" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `readonly="true"`.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 